# flutter runes , inside text Controller ��

Tags: android, flutter, character-encoding

Good day Comunnity

I am using a text Controller , I want to store the emoji + text value in MySQL database,

I am using this code ,

```
TextEditingController nameController = 
new TextEditingController(text: "");
Runes encoded = new Runes (nameController.text);
var name = new String.fromCharCodes(encoded);
print (name);
```

but the result it's not that I expected.

It's printing some like
John Doe   �

any idea how to achieve it?

thank you very much!

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringEscapeUtils Apache Library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

For saving the unicodes in database you have to encode them. So send your unicodes to server by encoding like

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(/* string message*/)
```

For displaying the encoded unicode in android

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(/* string message*/)
```